# Set default include directory in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I keep my header files in a separate directory from the .vcxproj files. I added that directory to additional include directories. What I want to do is include them in my project using quotes without giving the full path.

This is my file structure.

```
MySolution (Folder)
{
    MyProject (Folder)
    {
        Include (Folder)
        {
            Application.h
        }     
        Source (Folder)
        {
            Application.cpp
            main.cpp
        }
        MyProject.vcxproj
        MyProject.vcxproj.filters
        MyProject.vcxproj.user
    }
    MySolution.sln
}
```

This is how I currently include Application.h:

```
#include "../MyProject/Include/Application.h"
```

This is how I want to include Application.h:

```
#include "Application.h"
```

Comment: You can use additional directories option explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx). But then you can use via `#include <Application.h>` instead of quotes `"`

Comment: I know I can include them using angle brackets but I want to include them using quotes to differentiate them from library headers

Comment: The [suggested way](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include) of using brackets `<>` is seach directories and of using quotes `""` is for local directories. Although gcc has [iquote](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) option, I know no such equivalent behavior in Visual C++. It is better to use the suggested way to keep your code easily portable.